# NodeJS Request Module Google Maps GeoCode API Post

Tags: node.js, rest, google-maps, express, post

I've written a function that uses the [request module](https://github.com/request/request) to call the [Google Maps Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) via POST method which will be further modified to return latitude and longitude for a provided address.

However, it now returns the error:

```
Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: www.maps.googleapis.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.googleapis.com, DNS:*.clients6.google.com, DNS:*.cloudendpointsapis.com, DNS:cloudendpointsapis.com, DNS:googleapis.com"
```

I've confirmed that the variable address is being set correctly from the input parameter values.  Does this indicate that the final querystring being built by the concatenation of uri and qs is wrong?  If yes, how can I check and validate what that final string is?

My function is shown here:

```
var lookup = function(input) {
    var address = input[0].address + ", " + input[0].city + ", " + input[0].state + ", " + input[0].zip;
    var apiKey = '<mykey>';
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://www.maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?',
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        body: input,
        qs: {
            address: address,
            key: apiKey
        }
    }
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var info = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(info);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was the result of incorrectly adding `www.` to the url for the Google Maps API.  The correct string was: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?`

Answer (score 0):

in the big chunk of garbage "response", somewhere in there there is the final string of the link.

but you can always put the key manually like

```
https://www.maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=yourApiKey
```

it was key= or apikey= check the googleapi documentation for that

Comment: Thanks, when I was getting the error it wasn't allowing me to step into the response object.